# Importing existing table data to a new table in different database (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

i would like to import all data of a existing table of one database  to a new table present inside different database in postgres, any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Probably easiest way would be to use `pg_dump -d db_name -U user_name -t the_table -f the_table.sql` and then restore using `psql -d other_db -U user_name -f the_table.sql`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html) the table and [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgrestore.html) in the target database.

In case it is not an option, you should definitely take a look a [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html) (Foreign Data Wrapper), which allows you to access data from different databases - even from different machines. It is slightly more complex than the traditional export/import approach, but it creates a direct connection to the foreign table.

Take a look at this [`example`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html#id-1.11.7.42.16).